# How to get following Json parameters values with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following json data in a Javascript variable `result`:

```
[
Object { id="3443", name="Jack", date3="261"},
Object { id="50942", name="Mary", date1="12"}, 
Object { id="2524", name="Paul", date3="163"}
]
```

How can I access the name and dates values with Javascript?

The json data is produced by a php script I wrote. I am not sure how to be able to name the 'ojbect' which might actually help.

---

After reading the first comments I realized I actually forgot to use jsonencode before sending the data. So the object above was a php array and not a json encoded object.

Comment: To clarify, do you know the names of the properties?

Comment: That's definitely not valid JSON. You can't have `=` follow an Object property id. Also, there is no way to access your `dates` in an automated fashion, because there is an inconsistency between the property ids. E.g. `date3` vs. `date1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
alert(your_variable[0].id); // 3443
alert(your_variable[1].id); // 50942
alert(your_variable[2].id); // 2524
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the names of the properties then look into the [`parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) method exposed by jQuery. This enables you to map the properties to a type, of sorts, such as:

```
var results = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);
for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    alert(results[i].name + ":" + results[i].date);
}
```

You may need to tweak the inputs and exact use of the outputs in accordance with your data and requirements.

Comment: You don't need jQuery to parse JSON.  Behind the scenes, jQuery just uses `JSON.parse()`, which most modern browsers support, or an eval-style `Function()`.  If you don't want to use jQuery but you want cross browser support, you can use Douglas Crockford's compatibility implementation, available from http://json.org.

Comment: @Andy E: Thanks for the information - very useful, and something I didn't know.